# Angular 2 Getting full url in guard (lazy loading)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In angular 2.4, I am trying to the the full url that the router is trying to navigate to (not just that segment).  The two things I think I have access to our the router and the route.

```
constructor(private router:Router) {
}
canLoad(route: Route):Promise<boolean> {

}
```

Is there anyway to get the whole url?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think if you inject ActivatedRouteSnapshot you should be able to get the url from that.

```
constructor(private router:Router, private route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {

}

canLoad(route: Route):Promise<boolean> {
    console.log(this.route.url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could not DI the activated route snapshot.  I get a bunch on unresolved parameters.  The can activate provides the snapshot as an arg, but since I am lazy loading I need to use can activate.